# Sybase.Data.AseClient Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network

Tags: c#, connection-string, sap-ase

I'm trying to connect to Sybase ASE with `Sybase.Data.AseClient` but I get the exception:

```
Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network.
```

My connection string is:

`Data Source='MyServer';Port=4020;UID='userweb';PWD='pass_web';Database='Mydb';Connection Timeout='300';`

I know that our ASE server has enabled `ENCRYPT_PASSWORD`.

Is there a connection string property to enable password encryption?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your connection string should set the `EncryptPassword` property. A value of 0 means disabled. A value of 1 will instruct the driver to negotiate an encryption method with the server.

So try this:
`Data Source='MyServer';Port=4020;UID='userweb';PWD='pass_web';Database='Mydb';Connection Timeout='300';EncryptPassword=1;`